# Bash, how to hash value of a string?

Tags: string, bash

I want to simply convert a string of any length to an integer value. Each string will map to a unique or even non-unique integer. Is there any existing opensource command that does this?

Bonus points if it is unique, such as computing the lexicographical order via a bash command.

Comment: Must be an integer, or any unique hash will suffice?

Comment: Integer only (not the datatype, it can be a "long" or "big" int). So just to be clear, it can be a string that has any length of digits in it. EG: `[0-9]+`

Comment: I am interested to see how you give bonus points…

Comment: I would mark it as accepted over the other answers. But since rici's answer has multiple ways of doing this, each with highlighted differences, I marked his as correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to be careful about using `hash` functions from common programming languages. It has been common to introduce randomized seeds into hash functions, so that hash values are only unique for a single program execution. This avoids a denial-of-service attack noted in [oCert advisory 2011-3](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html). (As that advisory notes, the problem was described in 2003 in a paper presented to Usenix.)

For example, the Python hash function has been randomized by default since v3.3:

```
$ python3 -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
-2595772619214671013
$ python3 -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
-6001956461950650533
$ python3 -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
-7414807274805087300
$ python3 -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
-327608370992723225
# Python2 generates consistent hash values
$ python -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
1453079729188098211
$ python -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
1453079729188098211
$ python -c 'from sys import argv;print(hash(argv[1]))' abc
1453079729188098211
```

You can control hash randomization in Python by setting the [`PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED).

Or you can use a standardized cryptographic hash like SHA-1. The commonly-available `sha1sum` utility outputs its result in hexadecimal, but you can convert that to decimal with bash (truncated to 64 bits):

```
$ echo $((0x$(sha1sum <<<"string to hash")0))
-7037254581539467098
```

or in its full 160-bit glory, using `bc` (which requires hex to be written in upper-case):

```
$ bc <<<ibase=16\;$(sha1sum <<<"string to hash"|tr a-z A-Z)0
861191872165666513280590001082621748432296579238
```

If you only need the hash value modulo some power of 16, you can use the first few bytes of the SHA-1 sum. (You could use any selection of bytes -- they're all equally well distributed -- but the first few are easier to extract):

```
$ echo $((0x$(sha1sum <<<"string to hash"|cut -c1-2)))
150
```

**Note:** As [@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) points out in a comment, the above doesn't really compute the SHA-1 checksum of the given string because the bash here-string syntax (`<<<word`) appends a newline to `word`. Since the checksum of the string with a newline appended is just as good a hash as the checksum of the string itself, there is no problem as long as you always use the same mechanism to produce the hash.

Comment: A sidenote: here string adds a trailing newline. So this doesn't compute the sha1sum of the string, but of the string plus a trailing newline. It doesn't matter here, but if you really want the sha1sum: `sha1sum < <(printf '%s' "string to hash")`.

Comment: Things of beauty!  That `bc` one is my favorite.

Answer (score 18):

You could use the `sum` or `cksum` command (the [latter being preferred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_(Unix))) to generate a base-10 integer:

```
$ cksum <<< 'hello world' | cut -f 1 -d ' '
3733384285

$ cksum <<< 'goodbye world' | cut -f 1 -d ' '
2600070097
```

If you're interested in the math behind these simple hashes, check out the source implementations:

- [cksum calculates the AUTODIN II polynomial](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/cksum/crc32.c) used by Ethernet
- sum calculates either the [16-bit CRC](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/cksum/sum1.c) or the [POSIX 1003.2 CRC](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/cksum/sum2.c), depending upon the `-r` and `-s` command-line arguments.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.